# A neutral idiom with the same basic meaning of "For your information"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a more neutral way of saying "for your information"? As far as I know, it is often used to express impatience, or to be assertive that someone is wrong about something.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: The phrase is indeed sometimes uttered in a hostile, angry tone, but it is not hostile in itself. It is often used just to make it clear that the recipient of the information is not required to take any action on its basis.

Comment: @jsw It’s all in the tone, indeed, as FYI is as polite as “excuse me” is. In emails to the boss, I could substitute “just to post you on this,” as well as “looping you in.” In corporate settings, workers and bosses are bombarded with emails and spend energy triaging which ones to read, to process, to act on, to delegate, or to ignore/store/delete. FYI is a courtesy because it categorizes the message as needing to be read but not needing to be solved.

Comment: I thought you might want to know...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good sentence which includes the word *information* but does not need the possibly prickly *for your*:

> Here's some information you might find useful [or interesting, or
>   surprising, or helpful, or of value].

Or you could say,

> Tell me if this information sounds helpful or useful to you.

Or you could say,

> Here is some information you may or may not be familiar with. Tell me
>   how it sounds to you.

Answer (score -1):

The most neutral thing to do is just say it, without a preamble:

- Hostile: *For your information, I already fed the cat.*
- Neutral: *I already fed the cat.*
- Postitive: *Good question! I already fed the cat.*

---

- Hostile: *For your information, I have plenty of money for the trip.*
- Neutral: *I have plenty of money for the trip.*
- Positive: *Glad you asked! I have plenty of money for the trip.*

---

- Hostile: *For your information, New Yorkers are friendly*.
- Neutral: *New Yorkers are friendly*.
- Positive: *It's interesting that you say that. New Yorkers are friendly.*

---

- Hostile: *For your information, I love linguini.*
- Neutral: *I love linguini.*
- Positive: *You have me all wrong. I love linguini.*

And so on.